# which jar file do i need for class com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.DB2UniversalDataStoreHelper?

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-7, websphere-6.1

i've got ClassNotFound exception for **`com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.DB2UniversalDataStoreHelper`** when running my java application . Does anybody know where i can get this class, which jar file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_7.0.0.jar